# XSS attacks and encoding

Tags: javascript, security, xss

I have a very basic question around XSS in terms of data. While the common prevention technique is to encode the data, does that encoding needs to be done both ways i.e. at server-side, when it sends some response to the browser OR do we also need to encode (say a user input data e.g. search field) before we send it to the server ?

Comment: Anything concerning security must be done on the server. Validation/other datahandling on a client is done just for the convenience of the visitors, that must not have anything to do with security.

Comment: @Teemu this is not true in case of javascript applications (eg. SPAs).

Comment: @GaborLengyel There's nothing you can do on the client-side to prevent a user to manipulate the request before it's send. Notice, that you don't even need the actual page, you can post a request from another server ...

Comment: @Teemu I fully understand this, but DOM XSS can (and does) arise without any server being involved, in which case you do need encoding (even if implicit by using the right facilities) on the client.

Comment: @GaborLengyel What's that encoding worth of? A user can inject and execute what ever code they want to on a page, via the DevTools or even with an extension. If someone wants to hack their own account or something, you can't prevent it. If you're linking to a third-party scripts, then some checking might be useful, though.

Comment: @Teemu This is sometimes called "self-xss", and it is considered a vulnerability. Severity depends on the actual case though, but there might be ways for an attacker to exploit this. The most trivial case is when data is read from the url, say the hash part, on which an external attacker has direct control. But also when it's say a field on the UI, an attacker might trick a user into copypasting stuff. In a business app an attacker might be a colleague too! Note that facebook even considers the browser console as a threat, look at the console on fb. :) But that's not usually treated like that.

Answer (score 1):

You encode data (strictly speaking, only data that might include user input, but many times it's just easier to apply to all data) **right before it gets inserted into the page DOM**. In different scenarios this means different things, and that results in a lot of confusion.

To answer one of your questions directly, you do not encode data before sending it to the server, or before inserting it into a database or something. You don't encode data on the request side in general. The reason is that in a complex application, you don't know where and in what context your data will be rendered, and for different contexts you will potentially need different encodings. Your input layer has nothing to do with that, but this is not just an architectural question, you have no way to select an encoding until you know how you want to render that data.

Of course this does not mean you don't encode it to whatever "output" it gets right into, during the request. For example you apply encoding to prevent SQL injection if you have an SQL database, but that is done automatically by using proper data access layers, parameterized queries and so on. You also apply an appropriate xml encoding if it gets into an XML during the request and so on. But that is not about XSS, it's about preventing other injection vulnerabilities, and these things are likely done by your language or framework mostly automatically, unless you are doing something unusual or less frequent.

You also apply input validation to any input, you can validate for format (in case of say an email address or a date), or you can validate for desired character set and so on.

But in general, there is nothing wrong with storing data as you received it from the client, without any actual encoding. In fact, this is the right thing to do in most cases (see below for the exception).

Then whenever that data gets output in any way, rendered in HTML, used in a backend query (which can be LDAP or SMTP or SQL or whatever else), you apply the appropriate encoding, according to this context you are using your data in. For html you apply html encoding, but for example for javascript (html can contain javascript blocks, where this also applies!) you apply javascript encoding. This is an output thing in general.

Having said that, there are a few... well, let's call them special cases.

Modern javascript applications (like single page frontends) might manage a lot of data without talking to a server. User input sometimes gets written all over the place and so on. In that case it's the job of the SPA to apply appropriate encoding whenever it inserts stuff into the page DOM. This mostly means using secure facilities of your chosen framework, most modern frameworks are quite good at this by default, but you need to be aware what and how will actually be encoded an dinserted to prevent XSS. This is not at all straightforward in a complex SPA. Probably the most complex case is when you want to deliberately receive html from the client (say you have a html editor widget), save it to a server, and display it in the SPA again, possibly with a preview feature while editing, but this is a separate (large) topic, just something to be careful with.

One exception to the "not enconding stuff in the database" rule might be large, complex legacy applications. Sometimes you cannot guarantee that all (legacy) frontends to your data will apply proper encoding, so you might decide to encode data before writing it to the database. The problem with this is that then you cannot even write new code properly, because if you apply encoding again, data will be double encoded, which is also wrong.